# Chroma retriever/CSV Agent giving poor results, any advice on this?

Tags: python, openai-api, agent, langchain, large-language-model

I’m working on a solution for a client who needs an agent to pull data from a CSV file, which contains information about a provider’s location, services, categories, phone numbers, and addresses. Initial trials with chroma embeddings and a gpt-3.5-turbo LLM had inconsistent outcomes. However, switching to gpt-4-1106-preview and adjusting the chroma retriever kwargs “k” from 4 to 8 enhanced document retrieval but also increased token usage. The CSV Agent was less effective, yielding poorer results than the embeddings.

The adjunted image is a sample of my CSV/Excel file. Any advice is would be aprecciated.
[Excel/CSV File example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JoVA.png)

For context, my agent is an assistant that provides contact information for providers based on user queries. For example:

User: "asado barrio san vicente"
AI: "Aquí tienes información sobre asado en el barrio San Vicente:
Asadero Parrillero  - Teléfonos: 123456789, 123456788
ASADO LA CASA DEL COSTILLAR, Javier Rodriguez  - Teléfonos: 123456789  - Dirección: Example 123
Espero que esta información te sea útil. "

What should i try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.